# smart mapstruct mapping from JSON to DTO

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

i am working on a spring application and using Spring Webclient to make REST call to an external service. as a result, i have this object :

```html
{
    "error": 0,
    "message": "",
    "totalItems": 1,
    "entities": [
        [
            {
                "entityName": "Field 1",
                "entityValue": "String value 1"
            },
            {
                "entityName": "Field 2",
                "entityValue": "Date Value 2 in dd-mm-yyyy format"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

now i would like to create a DTO that contains two fields (String field1 and Date field2) and tell mapstruct to populate field1 with the entityValue corresponding to entityName Field 1 and same thing for field 2. how can i achieve that in a smart way ? ideally without looping on all entityName/entityValue pairs in each entity.

for now i have two DTOs representing my REST result :

```
public class Wrapper {
    private int error;
    private String message;
    private int totalItems;
    private List<PairEntity> entities;
}
and 
public class PairEntity {
    private String entityName;
    private String entityValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A little looping is included...

if `entityName` is unique, change your dto to use a `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, PairEntity>` (key = entityName) instead of `List<PairEntity>`. You'll need a custom jackson mapper or gson, depending which lib is in use...

Or create an new dto and convert the list to a map manually.

Then create a custom mapping in mapstruct and get the values from the map.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-to-map

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper

Comment: Thank you for your help, i am exploring your links.